# how to show images from web services in grid view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am getting the images from the web services in list view but i want to show them in grid
view. As i am displaying the images in list view,In grid view how i can do this ? please help.this is how my code looks:-

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSString *CELLIDENTIFIER=@"CELL";
    UITableViewCell *cell=nil;
    if (cell==nil) {

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CELLIDENTIFIER] autorelease];
        CGRect imageFrame = CGRectMake(2, 8, 80, 60);
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[arrayListG objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]]];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        UIImage *img = [[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data] autorelease];
        UIImageView *customImage = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:imageFrame] autorelease];

        customImage.image=img;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:customImage];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean TableView with rows into it as Grid view?

Comment: Why dont use a scroll view to show your images in a grid. how images do you want to show in a row?

Comment: how many images do you want in a row?

Comment: follow this tutorial http://www.iphonesdkarticles.com/2009/01/uitableview-creating-simple-table-view.html           you'll get it the first and second one in the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Gridview = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 320, 480)];//your frame        
Gridview.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
int row=0;
int column=0;
int rows=4;
int cols=5;
for (int i=0; i<rows*cols; i++)
{
    if((row%4==0)&&(row>0))
    {
        row=0;
        column++;
    } 
    else{
        row++; 
    }
CGRect imageFrame = CGRectMake(row*80+10, column*60+10, 80, 60);//your imageview frame
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[arrayListG objectAtIndex:i]];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    UIImage *img = [[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data] autorelease];
    UIImageView *customImage = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:imageFrame] autorelease];

    customImage.image=img;
    [Gridview addSubView:customImage];

}
[Gridview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(rows*90, cols*70)];
```

Gridview is your scrollview add it in IB or programatically as you desire in my case i have added it programatically. set content size and frame as per your requirement

Answer (score 2):

Better to use this awesome library for gridview 
How to implement and integrate in project everything is documented on this link.[check this out AQGridview](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView)

Answer (score 0):

Please modify your code as below.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSString *CELLIDENTIFIER=@"CELL";
    UITableViewCell *cell=nil;
    if (cell==nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CELLIDENTIFIER];

        CGRect imageFrame = CGRectMake(2, 8, 80, 60);
        UIImageView *customImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:imageFrame];
        customImage.tag = 1;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:customImage];
    }
    UIImageView *customImage = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:1];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[arrayListG objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]]];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
    customImage.image =img;

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try UIcollectionView a new control for ios,it is similar to UItabel view and easy to integrate.
Please have a look on these links

http://ashfurrow.com/blog/uicollectionview-example

http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12